# has an invalid "PUT" export: Type "{ params: { intentId: string; }; }" is not a valid type for the function's first argument

Tags: deployment, vercel, next.js13

Type error: Route "src/app/api/(checkout)/confirm/[intentId]/route.ts" has an invalid "PUT" export:
Type "{ params: { intentId: string; }; }" is not a valid type for the function's first argument.
Expected "NextRequest | Request", got "{ params: { intentId: string; }; }".
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPZO1.png)
what's wrong??

i want to deploy my project, but error